# How to join two collections from different databases in MongoDB aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections ***[edit] in two different databases.*** Say it as `collection_a` and `collection_b`.

> **collection_a**  document

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$binary": {
             "base64": "y5tcYX6t3kCCUHJtFF+RHg==",
             "subType": "03"
        }
    },
    "name": "some_name"
}
```

> **collection_b** document

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$binary": {
           "base64": "DT+2QXMycUuX1xLdiFNO5w==",
            "subType": "03"
        }
    },
    "parentId": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "y5tcYX6t3kCCUHJtFF+RHg==",
            "subType": "03"
        }
    },
    "Status": "Completed",
    "Progress": {
        "$numberDouble": "100"
    }
}
```

How to get `name` from `collection_a` using $lookup from `collection_b` ? 
Trying something like below, but I see no results.

```
db.collection_b.aggregate([
      {
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'collection_a',
       localField: 'parentId',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'name'
     }
}
])
```

> lookup only works if both collections are in the same database.

Comment: Tried your example and it works fine, binary data is not an issue

Comment: let me check, in my case `collection_a` and `collection_b` are inside different databases inside same mongodb server. I guess, that is the problem.. let me double check

Comment: yes, you cannot run cross-db aggregation

Comment: agree, another way is to do programmatically.